# How to fix timezone data in pfSense/freeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, time-zone, pfsense

We have special situation with timezones here in Russia. Recently government had cancelled timesave shifting and it was no timeshifts for some time, but recently they decided to make one "last" timeshift backward.

All operating systems, including Windows 8 and Ubuntu, shifted time correctly and automatically.

But not `pfSense`: it shows time hour ahead.

How to fix? Probably I can edit timezone somewhere?

**UPDATE**

Sample commands:

```
$ date
Mon Oct 27 14:53:34 MSK 2014
$ date -u
Mon Oct 27 10:53:41 UTC 2014
```

Current currect time in `MSK` was 13:53.

Comment: Does `date -u` show the correct [UTC time](http://time.is/UTC)? It seems pfSense doesn't actually _have_ timezone data at OS level...

Comment: See my update. Yes `date -u` shows correct UTC time, while `date` shows incorrect `MSK` time and it is different. Hence it HAS timezone data somewhere, just incorrect one

Answer (score 2):

Using pfSense 2.4.2 (current version):

- Access the webConfigurator GUI
- Click on the menu icon at the very top right of the window
- Select *System*
- Select *General Setup*
- Scroll about halfway down this options page to the timezone selections. You can choose either GMT +/- a specific value, or geographic locations, such as cities, etc.
- After the changes, you may need to reboot the pfSense device before it starts reporting the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research about pfSense and found that it is a very heavily customized version of
FreeBSD.

The standard init(8) and rc(8) procedures are replaced with PHP functions and most of the
standard configuration are not saved normally but are created from the XML configuration file at
system start up. Also the kernel is heavily patched to implement some of pfSense's features that are not available with the standard PF in FreeBSD.

There is not even a compiler on pfSense, and upgrading various components could lead to breakage as often config file formats and behavior change between versions that would be unexpected.

Conclusion: There is no easy way for you to update the pfSense system except with its own newer version.
Building an updated version on another FreeBSD box or VM is described here:
http://devwiki.pfsense.org/DevelopersBootStrapAndDevIso, but might be too much work.

However, version 2.2 of pfSense is available at
[Versions of pfSense and FreeBSD](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Versions_of_pfSense_and_FreeBSD) and dating from 2015-01-23, which most probably
corrects this problem.

Comment: `freebsd-update: Command not found.` Trying to install `freebsd-update` with `pkg` also failed. This is `pfsense` router based on `freebsd`, may be it is limited distribution.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer for pfSense.